# Deploying Containerized Applications on On-Premise Windows Server vs. Azure Kubernetes:

Tags: azure-aks

I would like to understand the benefits of deploying containerized applications on on-premise Windows Server versus Azure Kubernetes (AKS). What are the key factors to consider in terms of cost, scalability, and maintenance?

Deploying Containerized Application

Comment: Hi @phoenix725909, I think there are two orthogonal questions you're asking here: 1. Kubernetes vs traditional hosting models 2. on-prem vs cloud. I would suggest rephrasing the question accordingly. You'll also find plenty of literature once you start researching those questions individually.